# Пунктуация при вводном слове

Tags: пунктуация, невыделение-вводных

Правильно ли опущены запятые? Действительно ли вводные слова стоят в начале обособленных оборотов? Предложения следующие:

*До сих пор они не пришли, стало быть уже и не появятся.*

*Того, что они взяли с собой, должно хватить на сутки, двое, может больше.*

Answer (score 1):

**Вопрос непростой.**

Раньше по правилам 1956 года и по Розенталю вводное слово **не отделялось запятой,** если в качестве присоединительного союза относилось **к обособленному обороту**. Всё было ясно и понятно.

Правила ПАС **внесли разнообразие** в эту тему (вводное слово стало не обособляться на границе однородных членов и простых предложений в БСП). **И теперь, вероятно, можно выбрать решение на свой вкус.**

**Предложение 1.**

По Розенталю: До сих пор они не пришли, стало быть, уже и не появятся.

По Лопатину (ПАС): До сих пор они не пришли, стало быть уже и не появятся.

**Правила**

ПАС http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127

§ 94. Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, **не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения):** Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня  (Ч.).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Если слово значит находится между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, то оно выделяется запятыми: Прозвенел звонок, значит, урок кончился; Не уберегли ребёнка, значит, пеняйте на самого себя.

**Предложение 2.**

**Того, что они взяли с собой, должно хватить на сутки, двое, может больше.**

Я бы не стала ставить  запятую конкретно в этом предложении: запятых там и так хватает, а смысл понятен. В то же время многие ставят запятую, обособляя вводное слово (но у них запятых меньше). С большей вероятностью обособляется вводное слова ***а может***.

Примеры:

Филину было сто лет, **а может, больше,** но теперь он вспоминал разные страны и улыбался. [Сергей Козлов. Правда, мы будем всегда? (1969-1981)] [омонимия снята]

И тоже застрял ― минут на пять, **может, больше…** [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]

Ну и доставка за все по штатам ― по 20 баков, **может больше**, и до России баксов 160-170. [М. Письма из Санкт-Петербурга подруге в Саратов (2010)]

Лет ему было около пятидесяти пяти, **может, больше.** [Александр Иличевский. Перс (2009)]